# Split string into 4 arrays VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

So I basically have a super simple macro program use to record mouse clicks. Every time the user clicks it adds a new row into each of the 4 listboxs (Click, MouseX, Mouse Y, Time).

I want to be able to save the macros I create because I don't like re-creating them over and over...

I made a save function that saves all the data from the 4 listboxs into a text file that looks like this:

```
1
1
1
1
END!~
1020
1032
1134
1129
END!~
611
670
668
602
END!~
32
62
93
131
END!~
```

I can import this entire text file and split it by "~" that gives me array(3) like so:

```
    Dim bigstringy = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\llooker\Desktop\Macro Scripts\Macro1.txt")

    Dim strarr() As String
    strarr = bigstringy.Split("~")
```

I tried using

```
Listbox1.Items.addRange(strarr(0))
Listbox2.Items.addRange(strarr(1))
```

but this gives me an error....

How can I split the string into 4 separate arrays and then use those as ranges for each individual listboxs?

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
LISTBOX1:
    1
    1
    1
    1
    END!

LISTBOX2:
    1020
    1032
    1134
    1129
    END!

LISTBOX3:
    611
    670
    668
    602
    END!

LISTBOX4:
    32
    62
    93
    131
    END!
```

Comment: I just thought about this.. I can just write the macro out to 4 separate .txt files and import them 1 by 1... but that will make a lot of extra work and I was really hoping to keep the macros contained in 1 .txt file each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Listbox1.Items.addRange(Split(strarr(0), vbCrLf))
Listbox2.Items.addRange(Split(strarr(1), vbCrLf))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a super quick easy fix! can't believe I didnt think about this :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometime a simple old for-next loop is simpler to understand and use

```
Dim bigstringy = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\llooker\Desktop\Macro Scripts\Macro1.txt")

Dim strarr() As String
strarr = bigstringy.Split(new string() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim blocks = strarr.Length \ 4
for x as Integer = 0 to blocks
   Listbox1.Items.Add(strarr(x).TrimEnd("~"c))
   Listbox2.Items.Add(strarr(x + (blocks * 1)).TrimEnd("~"c))
   Listbox3.Items.Add(strarr(x + (blocks * 2)).TrimEnd("~"c))
   Listbox4.Items.Add(strarr(x + (blocks * 3)).TrimEnd("~"c))
Next
```

You have 4 lists and you write a block of items for each list, so splitting your text at newline allows to calculate the number of iterations required to traverse the array. At each iteration you read the blocks of data for your lists that are now evenly separated by the size of the block and add the correct set of data to your lists.

With this approach, when you write the listbox items to your file, you could remove the `TILDE (~)` character after the `END!` bookmark.
If you do so, then you could also remove that `TrimEnd` that I need to add 4 times just to handle this unnecessary (now) separator.

Keep in mind that, probably, this could simplified a lot if, instead of writing each listbox data sequentially, you write a line with the items at the same index in the four listboxes separating each value with a comma.
For example:

```
1,1020,611,32
1,1032,670,62
1,1134,668,93
1,1129,602,131
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm sure this solution would work but I would have to change a lot to get it working. you bring up a good point about my "END" I probably should've just used VbCrlf's but for now I think I've got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go fine human:

```
Private Sub AddValuesToListBoxes()
    Dim count = 0
    For Each list In Split(IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\values.txt"), "~" & vbCrLf)
        CType(Controls("ListBox" & Threading.Interlocked.Increment(count)), ListBox).Items.AddRange(Split(list, vbCrLf))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution thanks to PT_01!

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

    Dim bigstringy = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\llooker\Desktop\Macro Scripts\Macro1.txt")

    Dim strarr() As String
    strarr = bigstringy.Split("~"c)

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Split(strarr(0), vbCrLf))

    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(Split(strarr(1), vbCrLf))

    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    ListBox3.Items.AddRange(Split(strarr(2), vbCrLf))

    ListBox4.Items.Clear()
    ListBox4.Items.AddRange(Split(strarr(3), vbCrLf))

    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    ListBox3.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    ListBox4.Items.RemoveAt(0)

End Sub
```